# iOS : How install and execute Python script?

Tags: python, ios

I must execute a Python script on the iPad but I don't know how to do that (without use Pythonista). Indeed, I find some example of the desktop application but I don't want to make a desktop application. I must create an iOS application (iPhone and Android) without any computer.

1) I have a python's script for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello World!"
```

2) I have a Swift's application

3) I don't know have installed Python on my device and how to execute my python script.

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run python program in IOS Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657162/how-to-run-python-program-in-ios-swift-app)

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question:
[How to run python program in IOS Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657162/how-to-run-python-program-in-ios-swift-app)

As far as I know, there is no Python runtime environment for iOS except Pythonista. But you can do a lot with Pythonista, so unless you've got really killing arguments for not using it, you could give it a try.