# Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, swift-pythonkit

I am developing an iOS single view app in Xcode 11.4.1
I added the ***pythonkit*** framework in File>Swift packages>Add package dependancy and added the git repo: https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit.git

[image: My project tree looks like this]

When i try to import pythonkit and use it in 'ViewController.swift':

```
import UIKit
import PythonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myfunc()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func myfunc(){
    print("Hello...")
    print(Python.version)
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the 
path to a Python library.: file 
/Users/sayansen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp1-cjzcpyjbchjbrlbzuhbvpjlsttfp/SourcePackages/checkouts/PythonKit/PythonKit/PythonLibrary.swift, 
line 40
2020-05-06 17:42:27.320360+0530 TestApp1[35313:1897321] Fatal error: Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library.: file /Users/sayansen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp1-cjzcpyjbchjbrlbzuhbvpjlsttfp/SourcePackages/checkouts/PythonKit/PythonKit/PythonLibrary.swift, line 40
(lldb)
```

I tried to build a "Command Line tool" for MacOS in xcode. In that project i added the pythonkit framework as above and it worked like a charm! 
Why is this error happening for iOS app but not Mac OS app?

Note: I have already tried [this simmilar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126337/i-cant-import-python-modules-in-xcode-11-using-pythonkit)
Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can install `PythonKit` as below. From the project folder , please create a `macOS` App and follow the below steps.

1. Go to File -> Swift Packages ->Add Swift Packages.
2. Enter the url as 'https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit.git'
3. Then continue the process.
4. Disable App Sandbox in Signing and Capabilities.
5. In "Hardened Runtime" under Signing and Capabilities: check "Disable Library Validation".

Also Pythonkit is for macOS, Linux and Windows. Its requirements does not specify iOS. iOS doesn't have any python interpreter so it cant recognize 'python'.
Hope this helps !!

Comment: i did so but am not getting App Sandbox in Signing and Capabilities. i cant add it there.

Comment: I need ios app. Why will i create a MacOS app again?

Comment: Pythonkit is used to run Python code directly within the Swift. As you can see from their Requirements page, https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit, PythonKit requires Swift 5 or higher and has been tested on macOS, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Yeah os does it mean that pythonkit may not work with ios app? even though its swift inside alltogether?

Comment: Yes , you are right, Pythonkit is for macOS, Linux and Windows. Its requirements does not specify iOS. Swift is a powerful and intuitive programming language for macOS, iOS, watchOS, tvOS and beyond.

Comment: You have any alternatives for pythonkit in case of ios app dev? like 'pyto' etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657162/how-to-run-python-program-in-ios-swift-app. Hope this helps!

Comment: is there any way to Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library?????????

Comment: No i didnt work. iOS does not have a python interpreter. thats the reason it is not being able to understand any pyhtonkit api. so the way this works for MacOS it wont work for iOS

Comment: Yes right, so i have mentioned to create a macOS app .

Comment: Solution work for debug mode but when I create the archive for end-user then the application is getting crash due to Python library not found.

Comment: macOS app, Hardened Runtime - Disable Library Validation, App sandbox - Disabled(default) - Works fine!

Comment: @RavindraKumarSonkar Samething is happening for me too. Did you find any solution. If yes, then please share the solution, its really needed.

Answer (score -1):

I've forked PythonKit to support iOS. https://github.com/kewlbear/PythonKit  This Swift package will embed Python in your app via dependency.