# Can Python apps run on iOS devices?

Tags: python, ios

Can Python apps run on iOS devices such as iPad and iPhone, or is there a specific language in which iOS apps must be coded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657162/3835963) question.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I don't think that this is a duplicate. I am asking about **apps** written entirely in python and the other question is about having python **embedded** in an IOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have built-in mobile development capabilities, but there are packages you can use to create mobile applications, like Kivy, PyQt, or even Beeware's Toga library. These libraries are all major players in the Python mobile space.

If you want a single Application to work on all devices then you have to use cross platforms like Flutter, react native xamarin and phone gap etc. that application never gives smooth use and also having some limitations.

Except that, you can use Xcode (native by Apple) to create iphone and ipad apps(using swift, objective C language). For android application development, you can use Android studio(Using jave) etc.

Comment: But even if i used Kivy for example, the app would require the python interpreter to run ?

Comment: So to run a python app on IOS devices, the interpreter has to be installed on the device.